# Binary Search in C - wrong exit code when integer not in the array

Tags: c, binary-search

This C Binary search function is finding what it's supposed to but I'm getting the error: "\ expected an exit code of 1, not 0 " if the integer it's looking for is not in the array.  I have tried removing false at the end or removing the else statement but this doesn't work. Can anyone see why?

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    int min = 0;
    int max = n-1;
    int mid = (max + min) / 2;

    if(n <= 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

    while (values[max] >= values[min]) 
        {
            if (values[mid] == value)
                {
                    return true; 
                }

            else if (values[mid] > value) //value's on the left of mid
                {
                    min = 0; 
                    max = mid - 1;
                    return true;
                }

            else if (values[mid] < value) //value's on the right of mid  
                {
                    max = n-1;
                    min = mid + 1;
                    return true;
                }

            else
                {
                    return false;
                }

        }
    return false;
}
```

I just modified the code to the following and got exactly the same result. Thought this might narrow down the problem.

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
int min = 0;
int max = n-1;
int mid = (max + min) / 2;

if(n <= 0)
{
    return false;
}

if (values[max] >= values[min]) 
{
    if (values[mid] == value)
    {
        return true; 
    }

    else if (values[mid] > value) //value's on the left of mid
    {
        min = 0; 
        max = mid - 1;
        return true;
    }

    else if (values[mid] < value) //value's on the right of mid  
    {
        max = n-1;
        min = mid + 1;
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}    
else
{
    return 1;
}   
}
```

Comment: Why does it expect a return value of `1` if the value isn't in the array?

Comment: It should return `true = 1` when the value is found, and `false = 0` when the value isn't found.

Comment: Where are you getting that error from?

Comment: `true` and `false` are not native to C language. Where are they defined?

Comment: The error message says "exit code". That seems to be referring to the value you return from the `main()` function, not the value returned by the search function.

Comment: @SHG : true and false have been macros defined by `<stdbool.h>` since C99, so for the whole of this millennium.

Comment: @jonathan-leffler Of course, but when this is *exactly* what he's asking about it's important to understand where they are defined.

Comment: @SHG: Since the code is running, it's unlikely that they're the cause of trouble unless the OP has done something truly eccentric.

Comment: @Barmer - yes the checks seem to show that the program is correctly identifying when the integer being searched for is found but when it's not present then it's unable to exit properly with a '1'. There must be something causing it to then return to true.  I've tried changing the else to an if else and negating the while statement with (values[max] <values[min]) as an ugly fix but this made no difference. Same result exactly.

Comment: Note that the `else { return false; }` clause won't be reached because you compared for `a == b`, `a > b` and `a < b` before that.

Comment: It's probably not really relevant to your scenario, but [Extra, Extra, Read All About It: Nearly All Binary Searches Are Broken](https://research.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html) is interesting.  (Strictly, your code suffers from the bug described in the blog post.  But you aren't working on data sets so big that you'll actually run into the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Note that true and false return codes depend on the context.

In C - False is considered to be only numeric 0, True is anything which is not 0.

In Linux - it's the opposite when talking about return code (or exit code) of a process. True is only 0 (means exited gracefully), and False is anything but 0 (means exited with some error, depends on the code).

**Addition**: You have also a logical bug - your `search` function code is not working. When you're checking if the value is left or on the right of `mid`:

1. You shouldn't return anything, the while loop should just continue. In your implementation, the while loop exits after one iteration - always. Regardless the input.
2. You're updating `min` (in the left check) and `max` (in the right check) wrongly. You always update them to be the first/last indices and it's wrong. Every iteration the range that you're searching supposed to be cut in half comparing to the previous one.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried changing the 'else' statement to 'return 1' to simplify things even further but the result was exactly the same.

Comment: You have another problem in the code, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With your help I've finally got a winner. It seems I needed to remove the array name from the 'while' statement (values[]); and I also had to reference "int mid = (min + max)/2" inside each 'if/if else' statement.  Thanks everyone. Phew!

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n) //values = the array
{
    int min = 0;
    int max = n - 1;

    while (min <= max) 
    {
        int mid = (min + max) / 2;    

        if (values[mid] == value)
        {
            return true; 
        }

        else if (value < values[mid]) //value's on the left of mid
        {
            max = mid - 1;
        }

        else if (value > values[mid]) //value's on the right of mid  
        {
           min = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `else break;` It will never execute. So it is not necessary. `else if (value > values[mid])` can be replaced by `else`.

Comment: Thanks, BLUEPIXY.  I've modified the answer, removing the 'else' statement and it tested well. Awesome.

Comment: Note that although you're working to the spec of the question, in general, you would need to return `mid` to let the calling code know where the information is stored (it'll probably want to access other information based on that).  You then have to have a value to return to indicate failure — `-1` is often a good choice.  Of course, the function signature changes.  (The final `if` is redundant — if `value` is not equal to `values[mid]` nor greater than it, it must be less than it without any further comparison needed.)